# Forge Viewer - getWorldCoordinates is giving different values on different occasions

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

I created below function to get worldCoordinates back, but it gives different values on two occasions.

While clicking a dbId, I get dbid cordinates and I pass it to below function which give me world coordinates, but you can see while I save that dbId selection to DB and reloading page next time to see it back, it gives me different coordinates.
Why it happen so?

*saving dbid phase*

**dbid coordinates**
x: -26.277027130126953
y: 18.102033615112305
z: -7.173819303512573

**getWorldCoordinates**
x: 256.76347287180107
y: 306.8180434914181
z: 0

*relaoding page phase*

**dbid coordinates**
x: -26.277027130126953
y: 18.102033615112305
z: -7.173819303512573

**getWorldCoordinates**
x: 422.50000131979897
y: 249.49997927733767
z: 0

```
    function getWorldCoordinates(position){
        var screenpoint = viewer.worldToClient(
                    new THREE.Vector3(position.x,
                                      position.y,
                                      position.z,));
        return screenpoint
    }


function getObjPosition(dbId) {
```

```js
function getObjPosition(dbId) {
    const model = viewer.model;
    const instanceTree = model.getData().instanceTree;
    const fragList = model.getFragmentList();

    let bounds = new THREE.Box3();

    instanceTree.enumNodeFragments( dbId, ( fragId ) => {
        let box = new THREE.Box3();
        fragList.getWorldBounds( fragId, box );
        bounds.union( box );
    }, true );

    const position = bounds.center();
    return position;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I was unable to reproduce the issue...

Try live demo [here](https://jsbin.com/fotabas/edit?js) - refresh the page and see the world coords prompted when the model completes loading ...

Be sure to convert the coords after the model finishes loading (e.g. after the TEXTURES_LOADED_EVENT) otherwise you may get erratic results:

```
NOP_VIEWER.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.TEXTURES_LOADED_EVENT,()=>{
 alert(JSON.stringify(NOP_VIEWER.worldToClient(
                    new THREE.Vector3(-26.277027130126953,
                                      18.102033615112305,
                                      -7.173819303512573,))))
})
```

Comment: Even I was trying the db fetch call on GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, so I tried it with TEXTURES_LOADED_EVENT, still no chance. In succes handler of my fetch call it is doing worldToClient conversion.

Comment: I am not getting any clues why its not working although we followed the correct approach.

Comment: sorry it was mistake, a bug in fetch code...its working again...